# Right unit implies left unit if elimination laws hold

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(C, \otimes, I)$ be a set $C$ with an associative multiplication $\otimes：C\times C\to C $, and $I\in C$ satisfying the right unit law, $c I=c$ for all $c\in C$. If $\otimes$ satisfies elimination laws on two sides (i.e., $ab=ac$ or $ba=ca$  implies $b=c$), then $Ic=c$ for all $c$.

I think the proof should be simple, but I failed to procedure one.

Comment: Consider $cIc$.

Comment: oh, that's trivial. thanks a lot.

Comment: Now you can write up an answer, and post it (the software may make you wait a while). Then later you can accept it. That helps clear up the Unanswered Questions list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c \in C$.

$cc = cc$

(By hypothesis: $c = cI$)

$ \iff (cI)c = c(cI)$

(By associativity:)

$ \iff c(Ic) = c(cI)$

(By left-cancellation:)

$ \iff Ic = cI$

(By hypothesis: $cI = c$)

$ \iff Ic = c$

Thus, a cancellable semigroup with a left identity is a cancellable monoid.

Similarly, a cancellable semigroup with a right identity is a cancellable monoid.

$\blacksquare$